# Memory allocation threshold (mmap vs malloc)

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, mmap

Id like to point out I'm new to this so I'm trying to understand / explain it best i can.

I am basically trying to figure out if its possible to keep memory allocation under a threshold due to memory limitation of my project.

Here is how memory is allocated currently using third party libsodium:

```
alloc_region(escrypt_region_t *region, size_t size)
{
    uint8_t *base, *aligned;
#if defined(MAP_ANON) && defined(HAVE_MMAP)
    if ((base = (uint8_t *) mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
#ifdef MAP_NOCORE
                                 MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_NOCORE,
#else
                                 MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE,
#endif
                                 -1, 0)) == MAP_FAILED)
        base = NULL; /* LCOV_EXCL_LINE */
    aligned  = base;
#elif defined(HAVE_POSIX_MEMALIGN)
    if ((errno = posix_memalign((void **) &base, 64, size)) != 0) {
        base = NULL;
    }
    aligned = base;
#else
    base = aligned = NULL;
    if (size + 63 < size)
        errno = ENOMEM;
    else if ((base = (uint8_t *) malloc(size + 63)) != NULL) {
        aligned = base + 63;
        aligned -= (uintptr_t) aligned & 63;
    }
#endif
    region->base    = base;
    region->aligned = aligned;
    region->size    = base ? size : 0;

    return aligned;
}
```

So for example, this currently calls posix_memalign to allocate (e.g.) 32mb of memory.
32mb exceeds my 'memory cap' given to me (but does not throw memory warnings as the memory capacity is far greater, its just what I'm 'allowed' to use)

From some googling, I'm under the impression i can either use mmap and virtual memory.
I can see that the function above already has some mmap implemented but is never called.

Is it possible to convert the above code so that i never exceed my 30mb memory limit?

From my understanding, if this allocation would exceed my free memory, it would automatically allocate in virtual memory? So can i force this to happen and pretend that my free space is lower than available?

Any help is appreciated

**UPDATE**

```
/* Allocate memory. */
    B_size = (size_t) 128 * r * p;
    V_size = (size_t) 128 * r * N;
    need   = B_size + V_size;
    if (need < V_size) {
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return -1;
    }
    XY_size = (size_t) 256 * r + 64;
    need += XY_size;
    if (need < XY_size) {
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return -1;
    }
    if (local->size < need) {
        if (free_region(local)) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (!alloc_region(local, need)) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    B  = (uint8_t *) local->aligned;
    V  = (uint32_t *) ((uint8_t *) B + B_size);
    XY = (uint32_t *) ((uint8_t *) V + V_size);
```

Comment: I afraid no easy answer.... eg for file reading or writing usually mmap.

Comment: The above code won't try to allocate more than 30Mb _unless you ask it to_. Is there a reason you can't just avoid requesting too much memory in the first place?

Comment: I'm calling an encryption method which causes a termination due to memory issue, as I'm crossing my given 30mb threshold. So i traced the allocation to this function. Are you saying that if i just tell it to allocate 20mb it can still perform the operation with just 20mb allocated? I have updated my original post to show the call to alloc_region

Comment: why not write your own malloc that keeps track of how much is allocated

Comment: @Useless i think your right now reviewing code, I'm having errors when trying to allocate less memory now though. I think a new question would be needed.

Answer (score 3):

> I am basically trying to figure out if its possible to keep memory allocation under a threshold due to memory limitation of my project.

On Linux or POSIX systems, you might consider using [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) with `RLIMIT_AS`:

> ```
>          This is the maximum size of the process's virtual memory
>           (address space) in bytes.  This limit affects calls to brk(2),
>           mmap(2), and mremap(2), which fail with the error ENOMEM upon
>           exceeding this limit.
> ```

Above this limit, the `mmap` would fail, and so would fail for instance the call to  [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) that triggered that particular use of `mmap`.

---

> I'm under the impression i can either use mmap

Notice that [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) will call [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (or sometimes [sbrk(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html)...) to retrieve (virtual) memory from the kernel, thus growing your [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). However, `malloc` often prefer to reused previously `free`-d memory (when available). And `free` usually won't call  [munmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/munmap.2.html) to release memory chunks but prefer to keep it for future `malloc`-s. Actually most C standard libraries segregate between "small" and "large" allocation (in practice a `malloc` for a gigabyte will use `mmap`, and the corresponding `free` would `mmap` immediately).

See also [mallopt(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallopt.3.html) and [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html). In case you need to lock some pages (obtained by `mmap`) into *physical* RAM, consider [mlock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html).

Look also into [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/375893/50557) answer (explaining that the notion of RAM used by a particular process is not that easy).

For `malloc` related bugs (including [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)) use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).